# Object address in Ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, memory-address, inspect

**Short version:**  The default `inspect` method for a class displays the object's address.*  How can I do this in a custom `inspect` method of my own?

*(To be clear, I want the 8-digit hex number you would normally get from `inspect`.  I don't care about the actual memory address.  I'm just calling it a memory address because it *looks* like one.  I know Ruby is memory-safe.)

**Long version:**  I have two classes, `Thing` and `ThingList`.  `ThingList` is a subclass of `Array` specifically designed to hold Things.  Due to the nature of Things and the way they are used in my program, Things have an instance variable `@container` that points back to the `ThingList` that holds the `Thing`.

It is possible for two Things to have exactly the same data. Therefore, when I'm debugging the application, the only way I can reliably differentiate between two Things is to use `inspect`, which displays their address.  When I `inspect` a `Thing`, however, I get pages upon pages of output because `inspect` will recursively inspect `@container`, causing every Thing in the list to be inspected as well!

All I need is the first part of that output.  How can I write a custom `inspect` method on `Thing` that will just display this?

```
#<Thing:0xb7727704>
```

**EDIT:**  I just realized that the default `to_s` does exactly this.  I didn't notice this earlier because I have a custom `to_s` that provides human-readable details about the object.

Assume that I cannot use `to_s`, and that I must write a custom `inspect`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the address using object_id and multiplying it by 2<sup>*</sup>  and display it in hex using `sprintf` (aka `%`):

```
"#<Thing:0x%08x>" % (object_id * 2)
```

Of course, as long as you only need the number to be unique and don't care that it's the actual address, you can just leave out the `* 2`.

<sup>*</sup> For reasons that you don't need to understand (meaning: I don't understand them), `object_id` returns half the object's memory address, so you need to multiply by 2 to get the actual address.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that [object_id](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000339) returns the object address, but the unique identifier should solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @maerics: In MRI it definitely does (for all objects excepts Integers, Symbols, true, false and nil).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps on some versions; my nearest MRI (1.8.7 darwin) definitely shows different values between the default `inspect` and `object_id`.

Comment: maerics seems to be right, at least in my Ruby interpreter.  While the object_ids for Integers, Symbols, true, false and nil certainly are special (namely, they remain the same each time you run the program), the object_ids for everything else are not equal to the object addresses.  They are uniquely identifiable, though, and it is the easiest solution to implement so far, so +1.

Comment: @maerics: You're right, object_id returns `(obj|FIXNUM_FLAG)`, which is the address divided by 2. Easy enough to fix though, by multiplying the object_id by 2.

Comment: Although, upon looking through the current MRI 1.9.2 source, it appears that the object pointer value _is_ used for object_id (for non-immediate types) so perhaps the difference in reported values has to do with printf's treatment of "%p" vs "%x".  Anyway, agreed, sepp2k's solution is much better =)

Comment: @maerics: It's not because of printf. The reason the number is different, is that it doesn't properly convert the pointer to a ruby int. Instead of calling using LONG2FIXNUM (or whatever that was called), it jost `|`s the FIXNUM_FLAG (aka 1) to the pointer. This does make it a valid Fixnum, but not one which represents the actual pointer value (it represents exactly half of the pointer value).

Comment: @sepp2k: you're absolutely right.  We must have been reading "gc.c" and "ruby.h" at the exact same time =)

Comment: I have just one problem with multiplying it by two:  It adds a pesky little 'f' at the beginning of the address that I can't seem to get rid of.  I tried subtracting 0xF00000000, I tried a bitwise & ~0xF00000000... nothing's working on it.  Other than that, though, it looks good.

Comment: This isn't valid, It doesn't work on linux https://github.com/schneems/heapy/commit/1e827f196565657160f5b1d09e51b59c86c89439 can we update the snippet?

Comment: @Schneems Works fine for me. In what way does it not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. There is no way in Ruby to get the memory address of an object, since Ruby is a memory-safe language which has (by design) no methods for accessing memory directly. In fact, in many implementations of Ruby, objects don't even *have* a memory address. And in most of the implementations that *do* map objects directly to memory, the memory address potentially changes after every garbage collection.

The reason why using the memory address as an identifier in current versions of MRI and YARV accidentally works, is because they have a crappy garbage collector implementation that never defragments memory. All other implementations have garbage collectors which *do* defragment memory, and thus move objects around in memory, thereby changing their address.

If you tie your implementation to the memory address, your code will only ever work on slow implementations with crappy garbage collectors. And it isn't even guaranteed that MRI and YARV will always have crappy garbage collectors, in fact, in both implementations the garbage collector has been identified as one of *the* major performance bottlenecks and it is safe to assume that there *will* be changes to the garbage collectors. There are already some major changes to YARV's garbage collector in the SVN, which will be part of YARV 1.9.3 and YARV 2.0.

If you want an ID for objects, use `Object#object_id`.

Comment: Should MRI/YARV have used object id rather than memory address for inspect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing Array your class instances could delegate to one for the desired methods so that you don't inherit the overridden `inspect` method.